# How to know if a wordpress plugin is safe

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

There are thousands of **plugins** and **themes** available at **wordpress.org** and many other third parties. There is every possibility of bad plugins and themes being uploaded, which once uploaded could send info about the site to its owner. It could also send the information in the **wp-config.php** (A high security risk).

Please tell me how to protect wordpress sites from this other than by reading the code line by line. Also tell me if plugins and themes at **wordpress.org** are analyzed by the wordpress developers for **threats** like this before making it **available to public**.

Thank you.

Peace to All....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good article about the safety and security of themes that [best plugins for wordpress](http://bestpluginsforwp.com/3-great-plugins-making-wordpress-theme-safe/#.T0xmY_Egc64) put together.   Also you can go some off of the rating given by the community straight from the wordpress plugin site. If you keep with plugins that have a 4-5 star rating and lots of downloads/ratings, you will most likely be ok.  However, because this is an open source project, there is really not a 100% way to keep hackers and "bad people" from putting code in a what appears to be good theme/plugin that you are describing.

In this case if you have concern of a theme or plugin, I would always look over the code very carefully and make sure that it all looks good to you.  Of course this is always time consuming and if you are not comfortable with code, this may not be an option.  If you have questions about a certain set of plugins/themes, im sure if you post them here, there are many people that have used the plugin and maybe the theme before that can help you out.

From "Best Plugins for Wordpress"

> > 1 [TAC (Theme Authenticity Checker) Plugin](http://builtbackwards.com/projects/tac/)
> >
> > A very simple and straight forward plugin that will scan all files within your theme to >>check for any malicious or unwanted code.
> >
> > 2 [Theme-Check Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/)
> >
> > You may notice that a lot of free themes aren’t available directly from WordPress.org, >>the main reason for this is that most free themes don’t pass the tests that WordPress.org subjects them too. This nifty plugin will provide you with all the testing tools you will need to conduct the same tests that WordPress.org does. It’s also useful for theme developers who want to make sure their theme supports the latest standards.
> >
> > 3 [Exploit Scanner Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exploit-scanner/)
> >
> > This plugin isn’t just for themes, it’s for your entire site, so it’s worth keeping once you’ve checked out the theme you’ve decided to use on your site. It scans all files, posts and comments on your site for any possible exploits or anything that looks suspicious, please note however that this plugin will not remove any files.

Comment: Here is the actual link
http://bestpluginsforwp.com/3-great-plugins-making-wordpress-theme-safe/#.T0xrD_Egc64

Comment: Im sorry that didnt work either... I added the links that I wanted you to see in the answer

Answer (score 4):

As with *any* code you run on your own server(s), WordPress plugins are *caveat emptor*.

That said, popular plugins have probably had a fair number of eyes on their code, making it unlikely that they're doing something shady. You probably don't need to go over them with a fine-tooth comb before installing them.

Lesser-known/used plugins, however, should probably be looked over before you install them on a site/server that you care about.

WordPress.org does not review every bit of code that goes into plugins - the only time they even do any review at all is when the plugin is initially submitted to the plugin directory, and that's cursory at best (mostly just to avoid spam). A plugin's code can change drastically after it's initially submitted.

Answer (score 4):

Typically I will look at the feedback the plugin received on wordpress.org What kind of rating does it have? What comments/questions are asked in the 'what others are saying' section.

After making the decision to install the plugin, **BACKUP YOUR DATA PRIOR TO THE ACTUAL INSTALLATION.**

This is just good practice in any case, whether it's a wordpress core installation, plugin installation, or theme. If something breaks, you will have something to go back to.

Also making sure to keep frequent backups is a must. If you do get infected, you will want a snapshot.